# How to build simple_form for a hash field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called UserSetting with user_id:integer and setting:text,
The setting field is serialized as hash

I have another model called AppSettings with name:string, options:text
The options field is serialized as Array

I am trying to build a simple_form for the UserSetting as follow:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user_setting) do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.input :user_id %>
<% AppSetting.all.each do |setting| %>
    <%= f.input :setting, as: :select, collection: setting.options%>
<% end %>
</div>
 <div class="form-actions">
   <%= f.button :submit, 'Save Changes', class: 'btn-primary' %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

I am un able to make simple_form export :setting as a hash

Here is a sample of what AppSetting data currently looks like:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<AppSetting id: 1, name: "increase_prices_by", options: [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3], created_at: "2014-07-19 03:54:17", updated_at: "2014-07-19 03:54:17">, #<AppSetting id: 2, name: "hide_suggested_student_price", options: ["No", "Yes"], created_at: "2014-07-19 04:24:14", updated_at: "2014-07-19 04:24:14">]>
```

I wanted to be saved in this format:

```
{increase_prices_by: 0.05, hide_suggested_student_price: 'Yes', ....}
```

Comment: Are there any relations/dependencies between your models? 
And I (and as I see, not only me) cann't get what exactly do you want your App or, at least, action in controller to do?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, basically I have a text field in one of my app's model that is serialized as a hash, and I wan to use it in a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long a nigh I found the answer to my question:

First add the hash to the permitted params in the controller:

```
params.require(:user_setting).permit(:user_id).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:setting] = params[:user_setting][:setting]
end
```

Next add the simple_field_for inside the simple_form in the view:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :setting do |setting| %>
    Send newsletter <%= setting.check_box :send_newsletter %>
    <% AppSetting.all.each do |s| %>
        <%= setting.input s.name  %>
    <% end %>
```

Done deal!

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused as to what exactly you are asking but one thing I see is that you are making db calls from your view which is generally bad practice.  You should set

```
@app_settings = AppSetting.all
```

in your controller and each over @app_settings.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I will be doing so, but I was doing a quick testing to make sure it works first!.